# Query IP addresses (but not if same) in 24 hour period

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I want to count how many IP addresses in 24 hours access our data, we already store the IP addresses with timestamp. But I have not worked out how to query the IP addresses in Mongodb. So that I can group them by 24 hour from the last time the IP address accessed our server.

For example:

Say IP address `1.1.1.1` accesses our site at `01-01-2022T00:00` but also accessed it `02-01-2022T01:00`

This would be 2 documents, but we need to exclude the second one because it's in a 24 hour period.

But this should also be if someone accessed on Wednesday night at 11:30pm then accessed it on Thursday at 1am. It still needs to be seen as a 24 hour period.

Sample Document

```
/** 
* Paste one or more documents here
*/
{
  "ipaddress": "1.1.1.1",
  "accessDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666931400000"
    }
  },
  "accessFileId":{
    "$oid": "6274a3a881cf417136a8a4ed"
  }
}
```

I tried to use the answer below in our real life data, and it is not grouping them correctly.

```
[{
 $setWindowFields: {
  partitionBy: '$UUID',
  sortBy: {
   timestamp: 1
  },
  output: {
   accessCount: {
    $count: {},
    window: {
     range: [
      -12,
      12
     ],
     unit: 'hour'
    }
   }
  }
 }
}, {
 $project: {
  UUID: 1,
  location:1,
  timestamp: 1
 }
}, {
 $group: {
  _id: {
   id: '$accessCount'
  }
 }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) operator. Would be like this one.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
   $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$ipaddress",
      sortBy: { accessDate: 1 },
      output: {
         accessCount: {
            $count: {},
            window: { range: [ -12, 12 ], unit: "hour" }
         }
      }
   }
}
]
```

For the interval I use -/+ 12 hours, you may customize it to your needs. It is not clear at which exact time the 24-hour interval may start.

Comment: The above code, works but it outputs `accessCount:39` and others with `accessCount:4` it does not group them as 1 document.

Meaning on one day the IP address accessed it 39 times (I still see 39 Documents - instead of 1)